# Scraping JavaScript with Nokogiri

Tags: javascript, html, ruby, web-scraping, nokogiri

I have just begun using Nokogiri and have been able to successfully scape HTML pages. I am now attempting to scrape a certain page that is driven using a lot of JavaScript.

As an example to get me on my way - how could I scrape the decimal values from inside one of the blue boxes on [this page](https://www.betfair.com/exchange/plus/#/football?group-by=time)?

Answer (score 0):

You can't scrape dynamic values using Nokogiri, as they aren't contained in the HTML itself, but added to the DOM later. Nokogiri can only parse the HTML data, it does not build a DOM or run the page.

In order to get values from the DOM, you would need to be able to build a DOM and process it according to standards. That would require actually simulating a web browser.

A simpler way to do this is to try to find out what API endpoints the page uses to retrieve the values it then displays and making requests to those endpoints yourself. However, this requires some knowledge of how the page works, and isn't easy to fully automate.

Long story short: You're gonna need a lot more than just Nokogiri to do this.